# How to test a JavaScript Image onerror callback in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, image, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm having an url loader that I can pass in an URL and it will use a dynamically created JavaScript `new Image()` and its `src` property to load the url. In case an error happens, I'm logging it to the console.

The simplified JavaScript code would be:

```
var UrlLoader = function(url) {
  this.url = url;
  this.image = new Image();

  this.image.onerror = function() {
    console.log("image error");
  };

  this.load = function() {
    this.image.src = this.url;
  };
}
```

My question now is, how I can test that `console.log("image error")` is executed, when I run

```
var urlLoader = new UrlLoader();
urlLoader.load("any.png");
```

I created a [JSFiddle with the test suite set up](https://jsfiddle.net/murphyslaw/dy2dbc4h/), but failing specs and would appreciate any help on figuring out a way to test the `UrlLoader`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is line you use to check if log method was called

```
expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith("image error");
```

It's correct but problem that is `onerror` handler has not yet called by this time, because error event to be fired/handled not immediately but later asynchronically

You should change your test case to this

```
describe("A suite", function() {

  beforeEach(function(done){
    spyOn(console, "log");

    var imageLoader = new ImageLoader("any.png");
    imageLoader.image.addEventListener("error", function() {
        done();
    });
    imageLoader.load(); 
  });

  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith("image error");
  });
});
```

You can find more on testing async code with Jasmine in [this article](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/stips/using-jasmine-2.0s-new-done-function-to-test-asynchronous-processes.html)

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the link to the explanation on how it works. Much appreciated.